# How to POST in window.open()

Tags: javascript, html, post, get

When we do a `window.open()`, is there an option to specify `method = POST`? Since by default, it is `GET`?

What I want is this. The parent window has some form parameters (many in number) and they should be sent to the server on `window.open()`. It is not a good idea to append all of them in the `GET` url using query string.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use `window.open()` to open an empty window, with a name. Then you could use a `<form>` with a "target" attribute referring to that new window's name, and post it.

*edit* OK here's the idea.  You have a form on the page, and it can be hidden:

```
<form id='theForm' method='post' action='/your/action' target='TheNewWindow'>
  <input type='hidden' name='param_1' value='whatever'>
</form>
```

Then you get the results into your window like this:

```
window.open('about:blank', 'TheNewWindow');
document.getElementById('theForm').submit();
```

Make sure that the window name you use is a valid identifier (like a JavaScript variable name), or IE will get upset.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/CRFxV/) is a jsfiddle.

Comment: @Kaushik yes I'm working on a small test now ... I want to make sure I get the details right :-)

Comment: Thank you. This will not work for me because this will always open a new window. But I forgot to mention that only on click of a particular button I want the new window, else, same window. But thanks for your effort, I will accept the answer

Comment: In that case, you can just clear out the "target" attribute of the `<form>` tag when when you don't need a new window (or, alternatively, set the "target" when you **do** want a new window).

Comment: Checked your fiddle on Chrome,  Chrome version 39 ,it gets blocked by popup blocker!

Comment: @Mann odd. It still works in Firefox (33). Chrome's not showing any sort of obvious error.